# Designing amplitude modulator for class

Tags: amplitude-modulation

I am required to design an amplitude modulator for a class. The baseband signal is an audio signal x(t). The carrier frequency should be generated using a dielectric resonator oscillator with an output power of 15 dBm at an output frequency in the range of 2.0 GHz to 10 GHz. The modulated signal should have a mean power of 30 dBm with a modulation depth of +/-5 dB. An explanation of what these things are would be a good start, as the textbook for this course is of no help to me. The deliverable is a written report, which should contain a description of the design, complete circuit schematic, analytic description, circuit simulation results (maybe SPICE is best for this? I have never used it though) that confirm the required objectives. I have zero knowledge on how to go about doing this and am feeling quite overwhelmed. I need a starting point and maybe some kind of template or example to follow. Perhaps some good instructional videos and an explanation of how to do this that isn't very technical.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework problem with no effort shown. You need to talk to your professor if you're this confused; they should have taught you how to do all of this already.

Comment: JustSnapple, Find a different class or school. If your system is such that you are provided poor textbooks, poor lectures, inadequate labs, and no active-learning methods such as being encouraged to form small groups to discuss a course topics, or being allowed to reflect at the end of each class session about what you've learned and ask questions you still have, or being encouraged to work through an application problem with a partner before presenting to the class, or being encouraged to participate in class, group, or team discussion boards... then leave. It's not helping you to stay.

Comment: There are unfortunately no labs for this course. This was kind of just thrown at me. I still want to try to make the effort, I don't want to just instantly leave. All I'm asking for here is a starting point. Maybe an elaboration on the terminologies.

Comment: @JustSnapple GHz systems are complex. By definition. So you are already in difficult territory. There is no simple segue into this.

Comment: Such classes usually have RF pre-requisites. It doesn't sound like an intro class. It'd have taken some effort even for experienced EEs without RF experience - just to navigate the references and sort it all out. Those EEs would definitely look for existing circuits/designs that do something similar. Without proper training, it's rather unlikely you'll do it from "first principles" in the time you got. Look at existing circuits, and whatever references that go with them. If the textbook is of no help - there's plenty of other textbooks about this topic. Go to a library and look around.

Comment: If you've never used SPICE, then this class is not for you unless you want to be working on this project 18 hours a day for a couple of weeks. It'll take *lots* of effort on your part to do it, with so little knowledge. What is your electrical engineering background? How much course load do you have? How much work do the other classes you're taking this semester need? Just as a point of reference, it would probably take me a week of hard work to come up with something that I'd have faith in, and I've been doing EE with bits of RF here and there for decades, and have a lab for it too.

Comment: But that's all anecdotal of course. I know some engineers who would do it in less time with same starting knowledge level as I got - they are at another level though :)

Answer (score 1):

> I am required to design an amplitude modulator for a class.

I understand this can be overwhelming, especially when starting from scratch, but please put some efforts and start something by yourself before asking questions.

#### Basic Concepts:

1. **Amplitude Modulation (AM)**: It's a modulation technique where the amplitude of the carrier signal is varied in accordance with the baseband signal (your audio signal x(t) in this case).
2. **Dielectric Resonator Oscillator (DRO)**: An electronic component that generates a stable frequency in the GHz range. You'll use this as your carrier frequency generator.
3. **dBm**: A unit to measure power with reference to 1 milliwatt (mW). So, 15 dBm means (10^{(15/10)}) mW or about 31.6 mW.
4. **Modulation Depth**: It refers to how much the amplitude of the carrier signal changes due to modulation. +/- 5 dB implies the amplitude can increase or decrease by a factor associated with 5 dB.

#### Design Steps:

1. **Carrier Generation**:

   - Use a **Dielectric Resonator Oscillator** to generate a carrier signal in the range of 2.0 GHz to 10 GHz.
2. **Amplitude Modulation**:

   - The basic structure involves a multiplier where your baseband audio signal x(t) multiplies the carrier signal. This produces the modulated signal.
   - Ensure the modulated signal's power adheres to the 30 dBm requirement and that the modulation depth is within +/- 5 dB.
3. **Amplification**:

   - Given the oscillator's output power is 15 dBm and you need a mean power of 30 dBm for the modulated signal, you'll need an amplifier.

#### Simulation:

- **SPICE**: It's a popular tool for circuit simulation. If you haven't used it before, you might face a learning curve. There are plenty of tutorials online. Start with basics and then delve into RF simulations.

#### Report Outline:

1. **Introduction**: Explain the purpose of amplitude modulation and the requirements of the project.
2. **Design Description**:

   - Carrier Generation: Describe the DRO and its specifications.
   - Modulation: Explain how amplitude modulation is achieved.
   - Amplification: Discuss the need for amplification and describe the amplifier circuitry.
3. **Circuit Schematic**: Provide a complete circuit diagram showing all components and connections.
4. **Analytic Description**: Offer a mathematical model of your modulator. Discuss the relationship between x(t) and the modulated signal.
5. **Simulation Results**: Present SPICE results that validate your design. Ensure they meet the project requirements.
6. **Conclusion**: Summarize your findings and confirm that the design meets the given specifications.
7. **References**: Cite any resources or tools you used.

#### Resources:

1. **Tutorials on SPICE**: There are plenty of online tutorials for beginners. I'd recommend searching for "SPICE tutorial for beginners" on platforms like YouTube.
2. **Amplitude Modulation**: Look for educational videos on amplitude modulation basics. Websites like Electronics Tutorials or Khan Academy can be helpful.
3. **Dielectric Resonator Oscillator**: Understand its basics, especially how it works and its applications.

Remember, tackle this step by step. It might feel daunting initially, but once you understand each part and see how they fit together, it becomes manageable. Good luck!